# Render minicart without dropdown dialog

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I want to move the minicart to an offcanvas sidebar (foundation 6). I was able to move the minicart vial layout.

But it keeps rendering as a dropdown dialog (magento ui) so I would like the cart's items to render without having to klick on the title first.

```
<?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
     data-role="dropdownDialog"
     data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
</div>
```

This is the code responsible. So far my understanding is that

```
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

will be replaced with the cart's actual content. I do not need or want the dropdown dialog so I removed the mage init part:

```
<?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
<div class="block block-minicart empty">
    <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
</div>
```

This way only the top part of the minicart gets rendered and I see a JS error:

```
TypeError: $(...).find(...).dropdownDialog is not a function
```

How can I render the minicart "statically"? Or at least so that I can see the entire cart at once.

Actually I don't see the point of knockout js. It makes everything only more complicated. In addition the page renders with delay with items popping up after a while. How on earth can this be considered an advantage?

Answer (score 0):

@omsta, you can use below code.

Default it call once click on that show cart link.

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
```

It can auto display once load mini cart content. by using **"autoOpen" : true,**

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "autoOpen" : true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
```

OR you can use static display.

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty" data-bind="attr:{'style':'display:block;'}">
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
```

You will need to remove close button from : **/web/template/minicart/content.html**

Comment: Neither works. Your first suggestion doesn't make a difference at all. The second displays some elements but the actual cart items won't show. In addition I still get this JS error "TypeError: $(...).find(...).dropdownDialog is not a function"

Comment: have you tried static content deploy command?

Comment: Store is in dev mode, should not be necessary. But I cleaned all caches available.

Comment: I think dropdownDialog JS not copied in pub static content folder. That error coming for me while click on close button.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Ok I got it. I somehow did not realize the part about the removal of the close button. Actually all that was needed, was to remove "click: closeMinicart()" from the data-bind attribute. BUT: I have no idea how this results in a missing "dropdownDialog" error or even how to debug such an error.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting you.